# "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" in WinForms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to post to my own status on Facebook using WinForms and the Facebook .NET SDK. I am using the code below to post an image. I get this error:
"The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

I looked at similar questions but they deal with posting from a web app to other user's page which need a manual authorization on a confirmation page. 
I am not finding where I grant myself this permission on Facebook. I might be missing a setting in the code too.

Any ideas?

```
private bool PostImage(string UserToken, string Status, string ImagePath)
    {
        try
        {
            FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(UserToken);

           //for testing. id & name have values -----
            dynamic me = fb.Get("me");
            var id = me.id;
            var name = me.name;
          // ----------------------------------------

            var imgstream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);

            dynamic response = fb.Post("/me/feed", new
            {
                message = Status,
                file = new FacebookMediaStream
                {
                    ContentType = "image/jpg",
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
                }.SetValue(imgstream)
            });

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: (possibly outdated knowledge here) Granting permissions should be part of obtaining the token. Check code that you use to authenticate and there is likely list of permissions you are asking for.

Comment: I selected the permission in the Graph API Explorer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to post status on behalf of user means your application need to get permission from user using "publish_actions".

Refer : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-publish_actions